# Should cart be a synonym of the shopping-cart tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should [cart](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cart) be merged in as a synonym of [shopping-cart](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping-cart)?

Answer (score 3):

True! Good call! It's now merged!

Thank you